# Swift method to send email through MVC PHP page is very slow

Tags: php, ios, swift, email, model-view-controller

I made a Swift function to send an email to a specific email address with some parameters through a php page that actually sends the email. This is the code for my Swift function :

```
func sendVerifyEmail(email: String, verificationCode: Int) -> Void{

        var urlname = "http://.../email/sendPasswordReset/"
        urlname += email;
        urlname += "/";
        urlname += String(verificationCode);
        urlname += "/";
        urlname += self.userName!;
        let url = NSURL(string:  urlname)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!){ (data, response, error) -> Void in           

            if error != nil {
                print(error)

            }
            else{
                print("trying to show the verify view controller")
            }

        }
        task.resume()
        print("Email Sent")
    }
```

While this is the PHP function :

```
public function sendPasswordReset($email, $code, $name)
    {
        $file = file_get_contents('PasswordForgotEmail.html', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

        $code = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $code;

        $file = str_replace("{token_code}", $code, $file);
        $file = str_replace("{first_name}", $name, $file);

        $mail_in_html  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $mail_in_html .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $mail_in_html .= "From: <info@website.net>";

        $to = $email;
        $subject = "Password Forgot";
        $headers = "From: <info@studybuddy.network>";

        echo "send success: ";
        echo mail($to, $subject, $file, $mail_in_html."Study Buddy");
        echo "</BR>Name:".$name;

    }
```

My problem is that when I send an email, although it does go through, it takes about 5 minutes which seems to me like a very long time. I know this could be due to server issues. However, since I'm not an expert I was wondering if anybody can see anything in my code that could be causing this issue.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What actually takes 5 minutes? Which of the many steps takes 5 minutes? Is it the Swift code taking too long to send the data? Is it the PHP server code taking too long to process the sent data? Some thing else?

Comment: The PHP page in itself it's not too bad. The email still takes about a minute, but it's definitely better then when I send it through the Swift function. I think that yeah, the Swift is taking a long time to send the data.